# Axis2 Rampart Internal Server Error

Tags: apache-axis, rampart

I am struggling with Axis2 1.6.2 with rampart 1.6.2 ,jdk 1.5 and tomcat 5.0. I am using eclipse and generated All classes from WSDL. After installing rampart module I am getting some weird error. I am not able to figure out what is the problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.
The DEBUG LOG is as follows:

```
[DEBUG] Call Stack = DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.util.JavaUtils.callStackToString(JavaUtils.java:564)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.description.ParameterIncludeImpl.debugParameterAdd(ParameterIncludeImpl.java:352)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.description.ParameterIncludeImpl.addParameter(ParameterIncludeImpl.java:134)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription.addParameter(AxisDescription.java:108)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.setConfigContext(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:345)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:89)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1044)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:701)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:144)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:198)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:152)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:929)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:799)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:705)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:577)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    DEBUG_FRAME = java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)

[DEBUG] ==================
[DEBUG] Initializing Velocity template engine
[DEBUG] servletPath=/axis2-web/Error/error500.jsp, pathInfo=null, queryString=null, name=null
[DEBUG]  Path Based Forward
[DEBUG]   Returning non-STM instance
[DEBUG] JspEngine --> /axis2-web/Error/error500.jsp
[DEBUG]          ServletPath: /axis2-web/Error/error500.jsp
[DEBUG]             PathInfo: null
[DEBUG]             RealPath: /home/praveen/eclipse_workspace_highr/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/PaymentsWebService/axis2-web/Error/error500.jsp
[DEBUG]           RequestURI: /PaymentsWebService/axis2-web/Error/error500.jsp
[DEBUG]          QueryString: null
[DEBUG]       Request Params: 
[DEBUG] servletPath=/axis2-web/include/httpbase.jsp, pathInfo=null, queryString=null, name=null
[DEBUG]  Path Based Include
[DEBUG]   Returning non-STM instance
[DEBUG] JspEngine --> /axis2-web/include/httpbase.jsp
[DEBUG]          ServletPath: /axis2-web/Error/error500.jsp
[DEBUG]             PathInfo: null
[DEBUG]             RealPath: /home/praveen/eclipse_workspace_high/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/PaymentsWebService/axis2-web/include/httpbase.jsp
[DEBUG]           RequestURI: /PaymentsWebService/axis2-web/Error/error500.jsp
[DEBUG]          QueryString: null
[DEBUG]       Request Params: 
[DEBUG]  Disabling the response for futher output
```

Comment: And what is the actual error you get?